# ActiveAdmin 'show' layout not same as edit / new

Tags: activeadmin

I have customized the form for new/edit to use two column layout for the form fields.
The customization uses formtastic.

Shouldn't the same layout display for "show" by default? Instead I get the activeadmin default one field per row display.
How do I get to display the same layout in "show" as my form (new/edit) pages?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your layout?

Comment: @nistvan added a two-column layout screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

By default the show page has its own layout, so you have to use some css to arrange the inputs, or you can override this method:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/attributes_table.rb#L22-L43

```
@collection.each_slice(2) do |records|
 td do
   content_for(record[0], block || title)
 end
 td do
   content_for(record[1], block || title)
 end
end
```

Or create a new one, and use this in the show block:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views

    class AttributesTable < ActiveAdmin::Component
      builder_method :attributes_table_for

      def row_with_two_fields(*args, &block)
        title   = args[0]
        options = args.extract_options!
        classes = [:row]
        if options[:class]
          classes << options[:class]
        elsif title.present?
          classes << "row-#{title.to_s.parameterize('_')}"
        end
        options[:class] = classes.join(' ')

        @table << tr(options) do
          th do
            header_content_for(title)
          end
          @collection.each_slice(2) do |records|
            td do
              content_for(record[0], block || title)
            end
            td do
              content_for(record[1], block || title)
            end
          end
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Or something similar... I haven't tried it.

Comment: Nistvan, thanks for the pointers. I realized css was easier way out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the CSS hack

```
show do
panel "Mandatory Details" do
attributes_table_for contract do
    row :account, :class => "column1"
    row :customer, :class => "column2"
end
end 
panel "Dates And Financials" do
    attributes_table_for contract do
        row :start_date, :class => "column1"
        row :current_end_date, :class => "column2"
        row :end_date_w_options, :class => "column1"
    end
  end
```